# Assigning a string from a 2-D pointer array to a 1-D Pointer Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

For now, I need to do this using only arrays and pointers (so no structs or data structures)

I'm trying to append an existing table of data represented as an array. The way I do it is by getting the data from the file and placing it all into a pointer array which I convert via a function into a 2d array whenever I want to display it.

My problem is now that I'm appending data, my program crashes when it goes to the part of the code where I assign more data into my Pointer array

```
void appendCurTable(int oldSize, int newSize, string **ptTempData)
{
    int oldRow, newRow;
    string curFileName = "records/current.dat";
    oldRow = (oldSize/col);
    newRow = (newSize/col);
    i=0;
    int a = i+oldSize;
    readCurFile(curFileName, newSize);
    for(ir=oldRow;ir<newRow;ir++)
    {
        for(ic=0;ic<col;ic++)
        {
            *(tablePtr + a) = ptTempData[ir][ic];
            i++;
        }
    }
} 
//How tablePtr is initialized
void readCurFile(string a, int size)

{
    i = 0;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(a.c_str());

    tablePtr = new string[size];
    if(tablePtr==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Insufficient Memory Allocation.\n Program will terminate.";
        exit(1);
    }

    if(infile.is_open())
    {
        while(infile.good())
        {
            getline(infile, *(tablePtr +i), ';');
            i++;
        }
        infile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Error opening file.";
    }

}
```

readCurFile creates the new Pointer array that would contain the original data and the appended data.

Forgive the messiness, I've been tinkering here and there to see if the changes I make would fix it. After all those tinkering I found that the portion within the for loop is causing the crash.

Is there a way to make this work with pointer arrays or am I doomed?

Comment: Could you please give more of a concrete example on the values that you are using? on the other hand I think you need to increment a instead of i.

Comment: I've tried incrementing a as well  still didn't fix it.. The values are all in string data type.

Comment: There are some inconsitencies in your code. Where is the tablePtr coming from? then within the nested for's you are assigning based on a, while you are incrementing i and a nor tablePtr are moving, during all the cycles they are pointing to the same memory addr.

Comment: tablePtr is a global array at this time. I just tried using i itself and incremented i. It still crashes..

Comment: How are you initializing tablePtr?

Comment: I added the code to my question as I don't think I can do it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I was using referencing ir to an incorrect number. ir's function was supposed to be for the i I've declared in the function Append.

Correct code:

```
void appendCurTable(int oldSize, int tempSize, int newSize, string **ptTempData)
{

    string curFileName = "records/current.dat";
    i=oldSize;
    readCurFile(curFileName, newSize);
    for(ir=0;ir<tempSize;ir++)
    {
        for(ic=0;ic<col;ic++)
        {
            tablePtr [i] = ptTempData[ir][ic];
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```